# What about the rest of the universe?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, towards the end of the film,

> Thanos is successful in halving **the entire universe's** population. But, when this happens, the film pretty much only shows: (1) those who are in Wakanda; (2) Nick Fury in NYC; and (3) Spider-Man and company on Titan.

*But, what about the rest of the universe?* Why weren't any other planets and their populations shown?

Given that there are thousands of planets and populations in the universe and the audience has, by now, been exposed to a decent number of different species/life-forms/planets/etc., I feel like this moment in the film was actually underplayed since it only focused on the superheroes *instead of the entire universe*, which is what Thanos actually targeted (i.e., not just the people actively fighting him).

So, my question is: **why weren't any other life forms from any other planets and/or other planets and their populations shown during the events towards the end of the film?**

Comment: If we disregard the ~3 people shown in a post-post-post-credits scene and 1 or 2 unnamed Wakandian fighters, we didn't see what happened to *anyone* apart from our superheroes. And not only with regards to the disintegration but the entirety of the film's story. It was a film about superheroes fighting superheroes to save superheroes, entirely devoid of any of the normal people that were supposedly saved and/or killed.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Perhaps people and other life-forms weren't shown, however, one could argue that the sole reason these superheroes are fighting is to protect those common-folk/lifeforms. Additionally, major plot points occurred specifically for the sake of protecting humans (e.g., Strange and company going to Titan instead of Earth). But really, given the proposed magnitude of Thanos's end action, one might justifiably expect for the profoundness of it to be illustrated on a more grand scale, than staying tethered nearly exclusively to the superheroes.

Comment: Cliffhanger may be?

Comment: Even more interesting would have been when they all came back. Must have caused some interesting issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it has to do with the number of heroes there is in this movie. The cast for this movie was huge. When you have this many cast as heroes, you certainty have a problem with balancing everyones' minutes and screentime.

I think that is the reason, because if you have that many heroes you don't really want to "waste" any screentime with Warrior #53 and similar, you want to focus on the heroes.

Comment: But, but, but... Eitri (Peter Dinklage) made it, though - right?

Answer (score 3):

> why weren't any other life forms from any other planets, and/or other planets and their populations, shown during the events towards the end of the film?

Because they didn't need to be.

> Thanos is very clear what his intentions are once he gets all six stones - "fairly" half the population of every planet in the universe. We don't *need* to see what happens on Omicron Persei 8. We already know what's happening - billions of people are turning to ash. It's more important to the story (both to this film and the next) to see which of Earth's Mightiest Heroes have been slain by Thanos.

It's possible that this scene was intended to be shown, but was cut in editing due to the length of the movie.

Answer (score 1):

They did show a teeny bit indirectly that other planets were effected too.

1. Groot of Planet X
2. Peter Quill of SpartaX - (Peter Quill's fathers home planet)

(If anyone can think of any others i might have missed out, please do add)

I think to show more than that would just get tiring to watch as we already had a solid 5 minute or so of showing characters (important ones that too) get disintegrated/die. To allocate more time to show that it has happened on other planets might have been way too literal. 
It's implied that Thanos is wiping away half the population on every planet.